# wp_handle_upload is not accepting valid mime types

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, mime-types

I have tried at least 3 workarounds to get my .vcf files accepted during wp_handle_upload function in wordpress.

1. added filter and extension: I tried several types including 'text/x-vcard', 'application/vcard', 'text/anytext'. The filter addition of mime type worked for a while and then stopped working again.

   ```
   add_filter('upload_mimes', array('Daisy', 'daisy_mime_types'), 1, 1);
   public static function daisy_mime_types($mime_types){
     $mime_types['vcf'] = 'text/*'; //Adding .vcf extension
     return $mime_types;
   }
   ```
2. I added mime type as an array to the wp_handle_upload arguments.

   ```
   $vcard_upload = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES["vcard"], array('test_form' => false, 'mimes' => array('vcf' => 'text/*')) );
   ```
3. I used the plugin WP Add Mime Types.

Regardless of approach I am getting the following error: "Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons." However, if I use the WP Media Handler, I am able to upload the file so the mime type is accepted through other outlets.

The mime type is on the list of acceptable mime types when confirming with:

```
    print_r(get_allowed_mime_types())
   ` Array
    (
[jpg|jpeg|jpe] => image/jpeg
[gif] => image/gif
[png] => image/png
[bmp] => image/bmp
[tiff|tif] => image/tiff
[ico] => image/x-icon
[asf|asx] => video/x-ms-asf
[wmv] => video/x-ms-wmv
[wmx] => video/x-ms-wmx
[wm] => video/x-ms-wm
[avi] => video/avi
[divx] => video/divx
[flv] => video/x-flv
[mov|qt] => video/quicktime
[mpeg|mpg|mpe] => video/mpeg
[mp4|m4v] => video/mp4
[ogv] => video/ogg
[webm] => video/webm
[mkv] => video/x-matroska
[3gp|3gpp] => video/3gpp
[3g2|3gp2] => video/3gpp2
[txt|asc|c|cc|h|srt] => text/plain
[csv] => text/csv
[tsv] => text/tab-separated-values
[ics] => text/calendar
[rtx] => text/richtext
[css] => text/css
[htm|html] => text/html
[vtt] => text/vtt
[dfxp] => application/ttaf+xml
[mp3|m4a|m4b] => audio/mpeg
[ra|ram] => audio/x-realaudio
[wav] => audio/wav
[ogg|oga] => audio/ogg
[mid|midi] => audio/midi
[wma] => audio/x-ms-wma
[wax] => audio/x-ms-wax
[mka] => audio/x-matroska
[rtf] => application/rtf
[js] => application/javascript
[pdf] => application/pdf
[class] => application/java
[tar] => application/x-tar
[zip] => application/zip
[gz|gzip] => application/x-gzip
[rar] => application/rar
[7z] => application/x-7z-compressed
[psd] => application/octet-stream
[xcf] => application/octet-stream
[doc] => application/msword
[pot|pps|ppt] => application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
[wri] => application/vnd.ms-write
[xla|xls|xlt|xlw] => application/vnd.ms-excel
[mdb] => application/vnd.ms-access
[mpp] => application/vnd.ms-project
[docx] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
[docm] => application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12
[dotx] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
[dotm] => application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12
[xlsx] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
[xlsm] => application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12
[xlsb] => application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12
[xltx] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template
[xltm] => application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12
[xlam] => application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12
[pptx] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
[pptm] => application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12
[ppsx] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow
[ppsm] => application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12
[potx] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template
[potm] => application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12
[ppam] => application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12
[sldx] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide
[sldm] => application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroEnabled.12
[onetoc|onetoc2|onetmp|onepkg] => application/onenote
[oxps] => application/oxps
[xps] => application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument
[odt] => application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
[odp] => application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation
[ods] => application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet
[odg] => application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics
[odc] => application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart
[odb] => application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database
[odf] => application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula
[wp|wpd] => application/wordperfect
[key] => application/vnd.apple.keynote
[numbers] => application/vnd.apple.numbers
[pages] => application/vnd.apple.pages
[vcf] => text/x-vcard
   )
```

Comment: add_filter('upload_mimes', array('Daisy', 'daisy_mime_types'), 1, 1);
--- What is 'Daisy'  doing here ?

Comment: And Can you also paste the output of

    print_r(get_allowed_mime_types())

Comment: sure that is a long list and I have added it to the original question. the vcf entry is the very last one. Also the Daisy is just my class name probably should be $this. I have moved forward with my project by changing vcard input to use a custom wp media window. Unfortunately, that still doesn't change the strange behavior when using wp_handle_upload

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be related to how the mime types are defined in your web server configuration. I had the same problem with ogg (video files .ogv), line:

```
$mime_types['ogv'] = 'video/ogg';
```

was working fine on a localhost but then of client's server not, finally i figured out that I have to put an additional line:

```
$mime_types['ogv'] = 'application/ogg';
```

So I would suggest either checking your server's configuration or (if that is not possible) blindly checking other mime types like:

```
$mime_types['vcf'] = 'application/vcf';
```

Comment: Yes, I tried a little of that. I used application/vcf and it worked for a while and then starting failing. So did you add both of those then? so you had two of the same mime types with different descriptions?